# How to refer a method from a different file in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

The only thing I know we can do is have build.gradle  and have the following defined at the top for example to reference from other .gradle files

```
apply from: 'common-methods.gradle'
```

But I want to do the same thing inside a different gradle file.

Example:

**output.gradle**

```
apply from: 'gradle/common.gradle'

task output{
    doLast{
        outputResults()
    }
}

def outputResults()
{
   def output = ResultGrabber()
   logger.quiet("I have the output saved")
}
```

**common-method.gradle**

```
def ResultGrabber()
{
   return 1
}
```

When I did something similar I got an error that it doesn't know the method. I am not an expert at gradle but I have a feeling build.gradle is special compared to other .gradle type files. If thats the case then is there an alternative solution?

Comment: all .gradle files are equal ; is your path in apply from correct ?

Comment: That isn't possible. What you can do instead is define the `ResultGrabber` method inside [./buildSrc/src/groovy/](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources) - then it will be available inside all project build scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some weird reason I got it working when I placed the definition of my method inside build.gradle. So this is what my file structure looks like which works now

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: 'gradle/output-method.gradle'

def outputResults()
{
   logger.quiet("I have the output saved")
   return 1
}
```

**output-method.gradle**

```
doLast{
logger.quiet("Starting method")
outputResults()
logger.quiet("Ending method")
}
```

To be honest I am a bit shocked this worked because its build.gradle that's referencing output-method.gradle and not the otherway around. I made sure there was no pathing issue but in any case this solution allows me to avoid using duplicate code. I had mentioned in my post earlier that I already knew we could do something similar with build.gradle but I can't find any other working way. Someone had posted about defining my method inside ./buildSrc/src/groovy/ - but I haven't tested that out yet